# java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed Problem

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to run the following code but getting an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

I want to run `while (rs.next())` inside `while (row.next())`.

```java
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank_db", "root","");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet row = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM user)");

    while (row.next()) {
        int rows = row.getInt("id");

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user where account_number=" + acc + "");

        while (rs.next()) {
            // do something with rs
        }
        rs.close();
    }
    row.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();

} catch (Exception e){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey D Binara, I have removed all the irrelevant parts of the code for you. Next time please do it yourself, make the code the smallest possible to make it easier for your potential helpers! You will find useful instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: no need for the [tag:intellij-idea] tag... more like [tag:sql] or similar tag...

Comment: `ResultSet row` is already a lie. A `ResultSet` is a *set* of rows, not just one row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to have two queries open on the same `Statement` at the same time (*by default*).

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html) of `Statement` states:

> By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different `Statement` objects.

and similar from the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) of `ResultSet` (less specific):

> **Note:** A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed by the `Statement` object that generated it when that Statement object is closed, re-executed, or is used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

---

Unfortunately we are not able to know what is being done with both `ResultSet`s - eventually a better solution would be to use one single, more adequate query (e.g. using `JOIN` or similar).

Comment: In addition, it may be necessary to disable auto-commit if you want to execute multiple statements interleaved, even when using separate statement objects.